# Efficiency of String matching, Equals vs. Matches methods

Tags: java, regex, string, equals

Say I have to compare some string objects in Java, and I have to do it like a million times for a high volume program.  The strings will either be completely identical or they should not count as a match.  Which method is more efficient to use, equals (object equality) or matches (regex)?  An example:

```
String a = "JACK", b = "JACK", c = "MEG";
a.equals(b);//True
a.equals(c);//False

a.matches(b);//True
a.matches(c);//False
```

Both methods give me the results I want, but I'd like to know which one would be more efficient given the high volume processing.

Comment: Show us how you would use `matches` to compare two strings `a` and `b`. (I say that because I think you will realize how much more work over `equals` it is when you actually try to use this).

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to give an example and focus on the efficiency aspect.  @Wiktor Stribiżew, is it possible to remove the "duplicate" status?  I hope it is clear now that the other answer does not address my question- I understand the difference between matches() and equals() but want to know which one is more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check this by yourself by taking a big pool of strings and compare them in a loop. Before and after the loop, you take the current system time and then get the difference of the start and end time. See here: [Runtime](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPerformance/article.html#runtimeinfo_runtime) . But you should be careful because results may differ because of your hardware. Also it is important to be aware of the optimizations the JVM may do in background. That is the reason why you should compare many strings and maybe make an average value

```
List<String> bigList = new List<String>(); // put many many values in this list
String pattern = "pattern";      
long start = System.nanoTime();

for(int i=0;i<bigList.length;i++) {
   bigList.get(i).equals(pattern); //in another program, check for matches(pattern)
}

long end = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println((end-start)/bigList.size()) // this is the average time
```

Comment: Good answer, I did try something like this, and the equals method blew matches out of the water.

Answer (score 1):

> matches will probably be slower since it uses a java.util.regex.Pattern and java.util.regex.Matcher in the background. Both equals and compareTo use a simple loop, and should therefore be faster.

Answer found here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/487350/Performance/java/compare-strings

Comment: Thanks! You are correct according to the test I did.